# PHP Image Upload per HTTP Request Corona SDK

Tags: php, image, upload, lua, coronasdk

I'm trying to create an app that lets the user upload an image to my server.

However it always return:

> Error code 500 : Malformed Request

Maybe you have an idea what is wrong...

Here is the `.lua` code:

```
upload:addEventListener( "tap",
function( event )
if ( isPhoto == false ) then
    media.capturePhoto( { listener = onPhoto, destination = { baseDir = system.TemporaryDirectory, filename = "capture.jpg", type = "image" } } )
else
    local params = { timeout = 30, progress = true, bodyType = "binary" }
    local headers = {}
    headers.filename = filename
    params.headers = headers
    network.upload( "http://www.m7-studios.de/(link to .php)", "POST", onNetwork, params, "capture.jpg", system.TemporaryDirectory, "image/jpg" )
    end
    return true
end )

function onPhoto( event )
if ( event.completed == true ) then
    isPhoto = true
end
```

I'm using a example `.php`:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/yc3z9a9xgf5kkim/upload.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The mistake was the temporary saving of the image which seems to make problems.

Answer (score 0):

I just read it very fast, but you get this error if you dont include the following parameters in youre request:
HTTP_FILENAME
CONTENT_TYPE
CONTENT_LENGTH

this is written in this line in the php script:

```
if ((isset($_SERVER["HTTP_FILENAME"])) && (isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"])) && (isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_LENGTH"])))
```

To send the parameters to your php script you need to add them to your params.body as a string, probably seperated by &:

```
params.body = "HTTP_FILENAME='filename'&CONTENT_TYPE='filetype'&CONTENT_LENGTH="..1024*1024*5
```

Not completly sure though, see the link I posted in the comments.

Comment: Problem is, that I can't get image length in corona... However I deleted php image length check and tested it. doesnt work... :(

Comment: Sorry, I think I answered to fast. Reading [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112479/corona-sdk-lua-how-to-send-request-to-php-script-for-registering-a-device-to-g), You need to specify this values not in the headers variable but in the body variable ie. params.body="string with your variables, seperated with &".

Comment: regarding the image size problem, see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712622/how-to-get-the-file-size-and-delete-file-in-lua) and the answer talking about the lua file system at the end. ps tell me if its working so I will update my first answer.

Comment: Okay, got the problem. If I use system.DocumentsDirectory image get uploaded successfully. Problem is how to get this image to show up in my script? And why is it a problem to use TemporaryDirectory?